# Ember-Data extend a state of DS.StateManager

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the proper way, or is it possible to extend an Ember-Data state?

For instance I would like to add an new event handler to the "saved" state, but I have not been able to find anything that does this in the tests or the "documentation" ™.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem and I ended up copying everything in the closure that contains the definition of DS.StateManager. Unfortunately, since it's in the closure there isn't much else you can do... I'm going to work on figuring out a better way to do it, but for now that's the best I've found.

Comment: That seems unlike ember. They usually have an api that can be extended or a hook where you can add your own logic.